# getting a sum in columns from different tables in a sqlserver-ce database and displaying the result in a label control

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I have a sqlserver compact database with five tables A, B, C, D and E. There is no relation defined between the tables. All the tables have an `amount` column where I need to get the sum from the first four tables and subtract the sum from table E (i.e calculate if I should get a profit or a loss). I have searched for problems pertaining the same to no avail.

What I expect to get: `sum(A)+sum(B)+sum(C)+sum(D)-sum(E)`, which is to be defined as a command text passed to a `sqlcecommand` object. The result is to be displayed in a label control.

this is what I have so far:

```
SqlCeCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCeCommand();
            login = login.getLogin();
            SqlCeDataReader sqlDataReader;

            string cmdString =
                "SELECT SUM(AmountReceived) FROM A WHERE Date BETWEEN (@param1) AND (@param2);" +
                "SELECT SUM(AmountCharged) FROM B WHERE DateOfEntry BETWEEN (@param1) AND (@param2);" +
                "SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM C WHERE Date BETWEEN (@param1) AND (@param2);" +
                "SELECT SUM(AmountCharged) FROM D WHERE DateOfRequest BETWEEN (@param1) AND (@param2);" +                
                "SELECT SUM(AmountDue) FROM E WHERE Date BETWEEN (@param1) AND (@param2);";

            sqlCommand.Connection = login.connection;
            sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sqlCommand.CommandText = cmdString;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTimePickerFromPandL.Text;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@param2", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTimePickerToPandL.Text;
            sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

            if (sqlDataReader.Read())
            {

                labelProfitOrLossAmount.Text = "Ksh : " + //value expected to go here

            }
```

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM (
  SELECT AmountReceived [Amount] FROM A WHERE Date BETWEEN (@param1) AND (@param2)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT AmountCharged FROM B WHERE DateOfEntry BETWEEN (@param1) AND (@param2)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Amount FROM C WHERE Date BETWEEN (@param1) AND (@param2)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT AmountCharged FROM D WHERE DateOfRequest BETWEEN (@param1) AND (@param2)            
  UNION ALL
  SELECT -AmountDue FROM E WHERE Date BETWEEN (@param1) AND (@param2)
) [subquery]
```

If you put this between @" and " then you don't need all the string concatenation syntax.

Comment: thanks alot john, the query result displays just fine. what if i need to subtract the sum from table E? lemmi also try Dave's suggestion below.

Comment: I added a minus sign to the query so table E's sum can be subtracted instead of added.

Comment: I added the minus sign and got the following error :"column names must be specified for constants, expressions or aggregate functions when they occur in a FROM sub query".

Comment: You may have to add [Amount] after -AmountDue. That names the column and hopefully corrects the error "column names must be specified for constants, expressions or aggregate functions when they occur in a FROM sub query".

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using a single command in your query.  I think you can handle multiple ones using SqlCommand, but I couldn't tell you how to do it.  Here's a possible query:

```
SELECT sumA + sumB + sumC + sumD - sumE as total FROM
(
    SELECT (SUM(AmountReceived) FROM A WHERE Date BETWEEN (@param1) AND (@param2)) AS sumA,
    SELECT (SUM(AmountCharged) FROM B WHERE DateOfEntry BETWEEN (@param1) AND (@param2)) AS sumB,
    SELECT (SUM(Amount) FROM C WHERE Date BETWEEN (@param1) AND (@param2)) AS sumC,
    SELECT (SUM(AmountCharged) FROM D WHERE DateOfRequest BETWEEN (@param1) AND (@param2)) as SumD,                         
    SELECT (SUM(AmountDue) FROM E WHERE Date BETWEEN (@param1) AND (@param2)) AS SumE
) as tblSum
```

Then use "sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString();" to get the result.

Note that this is very inefficient SQL, but it should work.

Comment: I got an error :" error in parsing the query " when i tried using ur query, what might be the cause of this?

Comment: Not sure, I suspect I made an obvious and embarrassing syntax error.  Most likely you need parens around the subqueries - let me update with that.

Comment: There is an extra bracket applied before SUM and before AS in all sub query that is why it is giving error. So remove the bracket from         1. Before SUM  ( (SUM =    SUM   )            2.  before AS (   ) AS    =  AS )